# Dealing with multiple condition if statement in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, conditional-statements

Hi I need help simplifying this if statement with multiple conditions but I'm not sure how to as every attempt I've had cluttered my code even more :

```dart
if (isAirplane(element) && isFlying(element) && isRed(element))    return redFlyingAirplane;
if (isAirplane(element) && isFlying(element) && !isRed(element))   return greenFlyingAirplane;
if (isAirplane(element) && !isFlying(element) && isRed(element))   return redGroundedAirplane;
if (isAirplane(element) && !isFlying(element) && !isRed(element))  return greenGroundedAirplane;
if (!isAirplane(element) && isFlying(element) && isRed(element))   return redFlyingHelicopter;
if (!isAirplane(element) && isFlying(element) && !isRed(element))  return greenFlyingHelicopter;
if (!isAirplane(element) && !isFlying(element) && isRed(element))  return redGroundedHelicopter;
if (!isAirplane(element) && !isFlying(element) && !isRed(element)) return greenGroundedHelicopter;
```

---

**EDIT :**

Adding some extra context in which I'm using this :

```dart
 late BitmapDescriptor redFlyingAirplane;
 late BitmapDescriptor greenFlyingAirplane;
...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _initMarkers();
    });
  }

  void _initMarkers() async {
    redFlyingAirplane = await LoadBitmaps.redFlyingAirplane;
    greenFlyingAirplane = await LoadBitmaps.greenFlyingAirplane;
    ...
  }


 BitmapDescriptor resolveBitmap(Something element) {
if (isAirplane(element) && isFlying(element) && isRed(element))    return redFlyingAirplane;
if (isAirplane(element) && isFlying(element) && !isRed(element))   return greenFlyingAirplane;
...
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 booleans, so 8 possible outcomes, and these can be represented in 3 bits with values 0 to 7.

First define a function that turns 3 booleans into that integer, such as:

```
int bitmapIndex(bool isAirplane, bool isRedColor, bool isFlyingNow) =>
    (isAirplane ? 4 : 0) + (isRedColor ? 2 : 0) + (isFlyingNow ? 1 : 0);
```

Then store your bitmaps in a map, indexed by integer, for example:

```
final bitmaps = <int, BitmapDescriptor>{};
```

When you come to load the bitmaps store them in the map:

```
bitmaps[bitmapIndex(true, true, true)] = await LoadBitmaps.redFlyingAirplane;
bitmaps[bitmapIndex(true, true, false)] = await LoadBitmaps.redGroundedAirplane;
```

Finally, to access any bitmap, simply look it up:

```
return bitmaps[bitmapIndex(isAirplane(element), isFlying(element), isRed(element))];
```

Comment: perfect ⭐️ if I have to add one more condition I have to  write (isHappy ? 6 : 0) or can I write (isHappy ? 5 : 0)

Comment: You'd use the next power of 2, so 8, then 16, etc.

Comment: thank you do you think I can create a class named **`ResolveBitmap`** & put all of this logic inside it - *or is it not a good class name* I will call it inside my Stateful widget

Comment: Better class names might be `BitmapResolver` or `BitmapCache`. Class names should normally be nouns.

Comment: Thanks again : ) What if `isRedColor` is not a bool but an enum `color` with 3 possible values `EnumColor.red` `EnumColor.green` `EnumColor.orange`  ? : )

Comment: also I'm curious to know the name of this amazing theory you're using : )

Comment: Use 2 bits to encode up to 4 colors (you only have 3 so it will fit), 1 to encode airplane or not and 1 to encode flying or not - for a total of 4 bits (i.e. 16 possible combinations). There's no theory, but you could read about "bit packing" here: https://towardsdatascience.com/smart-way-of-storing-data-d22dd5077340

Comment: (color == EnumColor.red
          ? 12
          : color == EnumColor.green
              ? 8
              : 0) +
      (isHappy ? 4 : 0) +
      (isFlying ? 2 : 0) +
      (isAirplane ? 1 : 0); this did not work :/

Comment: That's not going to work: red unhappy = 12 and so does green happy. Red would have to be 16 or 24 - i.e. 10000 binary or 11000 binary.

Comment: ok it works if I set it to 16 thank you !  `(color == EnumColor.red ? 16 : color == EnumColor.green ? 8 : 0) + (isHappy ? 4 : 0) + (isFlying ? 2 : 0) + (isAirplane ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 1):

`Nested If Statements` may be used in this case. There is no need to use `else` conditions since you return a value for every case. The rest of the code won't run in any way if the condition is met.

```
  if (isAirplane(element)) {
    if (isFlying(element)) {
      if (isRed(element)) return redFlyingAirplane;

      return greenFlyingAirplane;
    }
    if (isRed(element)) return redGroundedAirplane;

    return greenGroundedAirplane;
  }

  if (isFlying(element)) {
    if (isRed(element)) return redFlyingHelicopter;

    return greenFlyingHelicopter;
  }

  if (isRed(element)) return redGroundedHelicopter;
  
  return greenGroundedHelicopter;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a similar approach as BBK, but extracted variables for the methods that are called > 1 times, not knowing how "costly" those operations are, and added the use of ternary operator to make it more compact:

```
  var isRedColor = isRed(element);
  var isFlyingNow = isFlying(element);

  if (isAirplane(element)) {
    if (isFlyingNow) {
      return isRedColor ? redFlyingAirplane : greenFlyingAirplane;
    }
    return isRedColor ? redGroundedAirplane : greenGroundedAirplane;
  }
  if (isFlyingNow) {
    return isRedColor ? redFlyingHelicopter : greenFlyingHelicopter;
  }
  return isRedColor ? redGroundedHelicopter : greenGroundedHelicopter;
```

Comment: `but extracted variables for the methods that are called > 1`  I don't understand which method you are talking about : )